# odd whitespace at bottom of fancybox-2

Tags: html, layout, fancybox-2

[image: extra space at bottom of fancybox2]

trying to use fancybox2 and videojs and am getting a white space at the bottom of the popup.

I tried to fiddle with the divs css but it wasn't working.
Stack overflow is not letting me post my question because I need more details!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

could someone create a videojs tag?

code:

fancybox-iframe.html:

```
<!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/fanbox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../js/fanbox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.4" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/fanbox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.4"></script>

<!-- Optionally add helpers - button, thumbnail and/or media -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../js/fanbox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/fanbox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/fanbox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.5"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../js/fanbox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/fanbox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#image").on('click',function(){
        $.fancybox({
                 'width'            : 640,
                  'height'          : 440,
                    'autoscale' : false,
                    'autoDimensions'    : false,
                    'scrolling'   : 'no',
        'type'              : 'iframe',
        'href'              : 'video-js-demo.html'
        });
    });
});
</script>

 <div id="wrapper">
     <div id="image">
         the video
     </div>
 </div>
```

video-js-demo.html

```
<head>
    <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <video id="video1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="640" height="480"
        data-setup='{"controls" : true, "autoplay" : true, "preload" : "auto"}'>
        <source src="Funeral_Planning_How_to_Plan_a_Funeral.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</body>
```

Comment: Looks like some margin or padding, try using Firebug in Firefox or the developer console in other browsers to identify the container there is a padding on (press F12 to access the console). A Link to the webpage would be helpful as the code you posted does not cover your full scenario.

Comment: what browser is doing this? try setting the correct options for the version (v.2) you are using (check the documentation http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs) ... the options you are using are for an older version of fancybox

Comment: chrome Version 29.0.1521.3 dev

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: I am facing the same issue in fancybox2 extra whitespace show in bottom.

Comment: I have found magnific-popup an alternative library, which is one option.